# My account on the Stack Overflow community has been deleted

Tags: support, moderation, deleted-users

I had an account on the Stack Overflow community with around 300+ reputation points, but today I noted that I did no longer belong to this community (I still belong to the Server Fault and meta ones though).

I clicked on "join" Stack Overflow again, but now I am back to 100 reputation points. Why have I been kicked out without any notice? How do I get my account back?

Comment: It seems unlikely that you were actively removed without any prior communication (unless you engaged in really evil behaviour, like spamming). Are you 100% sure you didn't mix up any credentials?

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to one of your prior questions?

Comment: here is a link to one of my answers (there is only my answer on this question), where I am now referred as "user4998164" instead of "tom". I have been answering and commenting more than usual last week but don't think I have been evil :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916810/aws-s3-https-api-requesturl-signed-with-temporary-security-credentials-to-acce/34918921

Comment: And I log in with my google account, still have access to my serverfault account, so no chance to have mixed my credentials with another account

Comment: Check your inboxes, if this was intentionally deleted you should have gotten a moderator message on your main account. If this account isn't a sock puppet, you can ignore this comment.

Comment: Yes I checked my inboxes but did not see any moderator message. This is my real account and I really don't think to behave badly

Comment: From a bit of digging, my guess is your account was ended due to being an alleged sockpuppet of another user who is currently under suspension, along with a second alleged sockpuppet account. Or perhaps just for being part of an alleged voting ring circulating that user.  Not sure if its alright for me to suggest this on Meta but hey you asked!

Comment: yes I asked, and thanks for answering. I will send a mail to the se about this, maybe I did sth wrong but this was not on purpose

Comment: lol 'I checked my inboxes' - how many inboxes do you have?

Comment: I have 2, as a lot of people I guess.... 1 professional and 1 personal, nothing weird nor funny about this I guess

Comment: @Tom there is [a very odd comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916810/aws-s3-https-api-requesturl-signed-with-temporary-security-credentials-to-acce/34918921#comment57583258_34918921) (comment just says "`Tom is right here.`") on your linked question by [a user named Thomas L.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4850422/thomas-l) who is suspended for "voting irregularities". There's a high chance your account was mixed up in the de-sock-puppetting effort. Definitely send a mail to SO using the "contact us" link!

Comment: Yes I ll do that tomorrow, thank you all for your help!

Comment: You can also flag one of your own posts with a custom mod flag, but I'm pretty sure the proper procedure is contacting SO directly (they're the ones who'll be able to reverse the damage).

Comment: That is an *astounding* coincidence that the only two users at your location were named "Tom L", both were voting for each other's posts, and both shared multiple items of personal identification. The two of you lead a remarkably similar life. I should note that had the two of you not coordinated votes for each other, none of this would have happened.

Comment: I would not be silly enough to name a puppet account with the same name ... I did receive no notification and was wondering why my account was disabled. Now I have an answer and will see with the support. That been said,  I will not spend hours trying to convince anybody, and I think I can live without my 300 rep on SO. Thanks again guys for your help on this! Cheers

Comment: @Tom good luck, and consider legally changing your name to  Floofataloof Shizmagig;)

Comment: Ha ha will do :)

Comment: @BradLarson crikey, I would've left a "don't worry, we'll fix it" at the end of that comment. You chastised the guy and then left him hanging for five hours until Ed showed up with no reassurance that anything would be done to resolve the situation! (Unless there was communication going on behind the scenes that the rest of us can't see.)

Comment: Your account has been restored. Again, thank you for your professionalism, and again, I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Brad Larson: http://www.snopes.com/inboxer/trivia/buxton.asp

Comment: I guess I was lucky, that my account wasn't deleted as well, since we share the same nickname :D.

Comment: Ha, you must be an instant familiar of the site now. Whenever people discuss and rule about sockpuppets, they'll chant "but let's not forget the curious case of Tom L!"

Answer (score 211, accepted):

I deleted your account. It turns out, based on additional information that we have received from another user, that that was a mistake. I am very sorry for the inconvenience. I am working with the Stack Overflow team to get your account restored.

Briefly, what happened was this: we had a *very* large number of indicators that your account was a [sockpuppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet)) for another user. We therefore deleted it.

Based on additional information that has come to light, it seems that what really happened is an extraordinary series of coincidences. You and one of your co-workers share a *huge* amount of information, both in terms of personal information and behavior on this site. This made it look like you were actually the same person.

To avoid revealing your personal information in public, I have sent you a moderator message with a little more information.

Please note that, as [Brad Larson explained in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315348/my-account-on-the-stackoverflow-community-has-been-deleted#comment298127_315348), the large number of votes that you cast for your co-worker's posts is what initially made your account look suspicious. In the future, please be sure you do not single out posts by people you know by voting them up (or down).

Again, I apologize for the confusion and inconvenience. Thank you for the professional manner in which you have handled the situation.

---

**Edit:** your account has been restored. Again, thank you for your professionalism, and again, I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Oh, wow. Indeed kudos for the OP's professionalism and calmness then. Not sure whether I would have managed it.

Comment: So there isn't a "reason" field you have to fill out for account deletions? Which could trigger a message to the owner, like "*Your account was found guilty of spamming/sock-puppetry/…*"?

Comment: @Bergi there is a reason field (a set of radio buttons) and a comment box, in which we can document for the other moderators what happened. In this case, I marked the account a sockpuppet and left some notes regarding the reasoning. That's part of what helped reconstruct events after the fact. The deletion does not, however, trigger an email to the user.

Comment: We'd be sending a scary number of emails to spammers every night if we did that, @Bergi...

Comment: @Shog9: I didn't mean an email, but rather a banner notice or so to be shown when they next visit the site. This would be effective for people, spam bots wouldn't care. Not sure whether it's feasible, e.g. if their credentials and sessions are deleted with their account this can't work of course.

Comment: I don't even tell coworkers or friends the name of my Stack Overflow account to avoid conflicts of interest in voting patterns. Though I did stumble across a friend's account, he hardly needs votes from me to feed his ego. As for similarities in name/job location, I once worked with four guys named David and two named Jeremy on a team with just 18 people. It happens.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Pretty sure that if you were to lose 300 rep points from your ~290,000 you would be able to manage it calmly :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Ed Cottrell, and no worries at all, everything is back to normal now. I will take care in the future, thanks for your advice. Cheers :)

Comment: And just for the funny fact, we currently are 3 "Thomas L" out of 6 engineers in my team :)

Comment: @Tom Wow!  I thought it was bad when a bit over half of a 2 dozen person team consisted of double/triple first names; but I don't think we had any shared last initials.

Comment: @user1803551 EVERY PENNY COUNTS

Comment: Nicely done Ed, you handled your mistake well. :) Just like a good mod should.

Comment: @tom I knew of a team of about 20, three first-name Bharat, three last-name Mistry, two of them being Bharat Mistry.

Comment: I've seen cases of same first initial, same firstname, same address, and same date of birth - twins, living at home.

Comment: Sounds like a classic entity resolution problem.

Comment: Dear @EdCottrell thanks god some admins like you exist.

Comment: @ErdincAy Thanks; that's very kind.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Appreciate it.

Comment: @DanNeely In my Boy Scout troop when I was young, out of ~30 boys, 7 were named Chris, 2 of those 7 shared a last name, and 2 shared a birthday. The law of large numbers in action.

Comment: @Shog9: `We'd be sending a scary number of emails to spammers every night` Spamming the spammers. And the problem with that is...? :-)

Comment: Statistically, no matter what the odds, all events *have to occur* given enough time.

Comment: Spammer spammers spamming spammers with spam might seem appealing... But you're still becoming a spammer, @eric

Comment: @Ben I see what you did there:P

Comment: @AndrasDeak, Ha! I meant same lastname of course!

Comment: @tom the really important question is how are you told apart? Nicknames?

Comment: I am sorry but this is very funny! :D :D Glad that in the end everything is solved peacefully... :)

Comment: @yochannah :p we call with nicknames, but clients are confusing all the time :p even our boss is getting crazy about this: "Thomas come in please... no not you... no the third one..."  ^^