# 2018 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

Stack Overflow is scheduled for its tenth election [next week, March 12th](https://stackoverflow.com/election/10). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364498/2018-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

As we've been doing in [previous years](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351972/2017-moderator-election-qa-question-collection), we're collecting questions one week in advance.

Here's how it'll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, March 12th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, because Daylight Savings Time happens to pass on the intervening Sunday), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at currently.
- Feel free to peruse the questionnaires from previous years: [2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289449/2015-moderator-election-qa-question-collection), [2015 round two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309753/fall-2015-moderator-election-qa-question-collection), [2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337191/2016-stack-overflow-moderator-election-qa-question-collection), [2017](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351972/2017-moderator-election-qa-question-collection)
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, typically containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because now that the [questionnaire has been posted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364498/2018-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire?cb=1), further answers to this question are pointless.

Comment: That reasoning seems to make sense, but a custom reason would probably have served a better purpose here.

Answer (score 171):

Stack Overflow seems to be burning moderators; the moderator review queue is huge; you handle 100 flags, but when you are done there are already 200 new flags.

Why do you think it will be fun to handle all these flags every day? What will make you survive more than a few months?

Comment: When you're sufficiently unhinged, anything is fun to you.

Comment: sometimes you handle 10 serial voting flags, spend like 2 hours or so, and feel good about yourself. Before you refresh the flag queue and suddenly there are 80 more.

Comment: I like this question. Frame of mind is something that can't be taught easily.

Comment: That's the only relevant question. Can you survive the grind?

Comment: @BoltClock Am I allowed to say that that's relatable? or do I need to have another 2k reviews under my belt first?

Answer (score 95):

I'll pick up [Brad's classic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289449/2015-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/289454#289454):

> A question is asked and receives some very good answers. The asker then flags this question and asks for it to be deleted because having it up will cause them trouble at work or school. Do you delete the question?

Answer (score 54):

A resubmit from [last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351981/2607247) and [2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337192/2607247), as this is always relevant:

> A user has been criticizing your moderation decisions on Meta. This has been occurring frequently over the course of a couple weeks. Some of these posts are very constructively made, with examples and reasoning, while some are more rants. While any mistakes you've made that have come to light were corrected when brought up, it seems that almost every day the user is finding something you've done to draw attention to.
>
> The user is a high rep user and generally does not cause trouble, but does seem to have an issue with your moderation style. How do you handle this situation?

Answer (score 50):

A favorite from previous elections:

> Do you have any Meta posts that you're particularly proud of, or that you feel best demonstrate your moderation style?

Comment: I remember this one ;)

Comment: Do titles of burnination requests count?

Answer (score 47):

As a moderator, you see something useful or interesting in a question by a low-reputation user, however there are a lot of downvotes and couple of flags on this question. Will you trust your gut and edit the question or otherwise override the community, or close it based on the opinion of these other reputable users?

Comment: Not sure if this has been asked before, but I like it. I find myself going against popular opinion on what makes a good or bad question too often for comfort, and I'd like to hear others' thoughts on this. Note that this question is not referring to taking pity on users, but dealing with legitimately (and surprisingly) good questions by users with an otherwise poor track record, that simply need substantive editing and are not otherwise off-topic, poorly researched, etc.

Answer (score 43):

As we all know, Stack Overflow is near its completion (*[mature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364152/2018-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/364160?noredirect=1#comment563600_364160)*) (over its top if you like, or [even](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364152/2018-moderator-election-qa-question-collection#comment562595_364160) *has its way of doing things*). The old-timers have their reputation, moderation tools and the occasional brawl on Meta. It is time for the next generation to take the wheel.

How will you moderate the new flood of users and their content, given that most of them have different expectations from the current inhabitants? Are you going to defend what we currently have or are you going on a journey to shape the community to make them ready for the next 6 to 8 years?

Please take a stand and elaborate.

Comment: This question seems to be begging the question over whether Stack Overflow is "near its completion". I don't think that's clear or obvious.

Comment: It depends on the reader what the question is begging for.

Comment: Would this question be better posed towards the community moderation team?  It feels like, while on paper, this is a good question to ask an elected mod, but this is more a discussion that the CM team should be having IMO.

Comment: I think this question stands much better with the first paragraph removed. It seems like confusing (and falsely-posed) noise to the crux of the question, which is "how will you bridge the gap in expectations between new users vs old users"

Comment: I feel it needs a context before that question makes sense. The first paragraph stays. if that makes it a bad question to be asked to a mod, so be it.

Comment: My favorite so far.

Comment: Could you clarify the meaning behind 'near it's completion'? Are you referring to it being near feature-complete, or that the usage of the site is on the decline?

Comment: @Rob you are free to read in it what you like. [I was thinking harvest stage](https://www.marketing91.com/product-life-cycle/) (notice that both product and customers are mentioned there)

Comment: Very good question if you replace *"is near its completion"* with something like *"has its way of doing things"*. The relation between the wants (inertia?) of the old users and the desires of the new users merits discussion.

Comment: "Mature" would be preferable to "near its completion."

Comment: My vote goes to the first candidate to make a vague but ominous reference to "The Great Culling" as an answer to this.

Comment: It basically depend on how the question asked or answer given is of great quality then it gets the award or reputation.

Answer (score 39):

A [user who consistently asks poorly-researched questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358678/do-we-need-to-instill-some-common-sense-into-minds-of-users-who-keep-asking-bad) gets flagged by another user. This might be flags like:

> This user is known for asking a question every few hours without showing any research effort whatsoever. Please send them a warning that this isn't how this site works

Or:

> Of their last 15 questions, 14 are about very basic Git issues. Perhaps warn them they should search before asking yet another question?

Or:

> User is asking a lot of low-quality, zero-effort questions. Their last four from the past 24 hours were about reading a text file, counting its lines and matching text with a regex.

Or:

> Not necessarily this question in particular, but this user is asking a lot of low-effort, zero-research questions, basically treating Stack Overflow as their personal helpdesk without leaving anything of much value for other users. Perhaps a warning should be issued?

What will you do?

Answer (score 27):

A lot has been said and asked about what a moderator *is* and what a moderator *does*.

What do moderators *not* do? That is, other than "violate the rules" (which is already a given), what are the most important behaviors that a moderator should avoid engaging in or should make a valiant effort to minimize? Another way to phrase this is to ask: What are the most important *unwritten* behavior rules for mods that are not found in any SO/SE policy, AUP, code of ethics, or legal statute?

Answer (score 27):

Since this has been ramping up lately, how do you feel about investigating lots of serial voting?

Investigating voting fraud can sometimes take a long stretch of time (according to moderator sources, around 20 minutes per flag). Do you see yourself having the continuous time to do this (irrespective of the 30 minutes a day guideline)?

How would you feel about users using semi-automated tools to report serial voting via flags?

Comment: I don't like where this is going, particularly the second paragraph. Certainly anyone would prefer a candidate who is willing to put in more time than not. But having the candidates commit to this during nomination phase will likely put undue pressure on the current mods to also dedicate more time.

Answer (score 26):

This is a negative of [what Andy asked last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351978) (and [this year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364154) as well):

> Are there any meta posts which you are not proud of? In other words, if you ever ask a meta post, and it receives a lot of negative feedback, what would you do? (Would you ask for it to be dissociated from your account?)

Comment: Answers to "what is your greatest weakness" type of questions are rarely illuminating.

Comment: One could also interpret it like "what did you learn from your missteps".

Comment: @FTP True, but this, specifically, can be illuminating as to the person being willing to take responsibility for their actions, be they good or bad, and be willing to accept that others may not share their views. Taking ownership of these is an important quality for a moderator.

Comment: @FTP sometimes moderators screw up. They can handle that in different ways. My favourite [example1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315348/my-account-on-the-stack-overflow-community-has-been-deleted/315367#315367) and [example2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315699/5067311). This subject is very much relevant in how I assess the spine content of a moderator candidate.

Answer (score 21):

Our community is more sophisticated than ever before.  We have the ability to script out a lot of the mundane and tedious parts of moderation, ranging from quality-of-life improvements while working the queue, to automated scripts being able to flag comments with incredibly accuracy.

Suppose now that you're elected as a moderator, yet you *haven't* heard of these endeavors or haven't really seen what fruits they've bore.  A user has come up for flagging an *inhuman* amount of content.  However, their flagging accuracy is *quite* high (99.999%).  Despite this, there is the impression of abusive flagging patterns with this person - either with some strange flags (for the few that are in error), or they seem to be concentrated on a few individuals.  How would you handle this situation?

Comment: "A user has come up for flagging an inhuman amount of content." What do you mean by "has come up"? Has been mod flagged? Has been identified by some automated system? Has been soloed out in a Meta post?

Comment: @TylerH:  Since I know very little about how moderators are notified about activty...let's say, "A little bird told them".  This covers automatic flags and user-submitted flags.

Comment: What is "abusive" flagging? Are you referring more to cases where a post is flagged with a flag that no rational, educated person would think applies (e.g. flagging anything and everything as Spam or flagging highly detailed, correct answers as VLQ or NAA), or are you referring to cases where flags seem to be targeted at a specific user or group of users, *even if those flags are correct*?

Comment: @RobertColumbia:  Yes.

Comment: @Makoto which one is it?

Comment: @RobertColumbia:  I just told you which.  *Both*.

Answer (score 20):

How do you plan on handling a group of experienced Stack Overflow users who think moderators should not interfere in the way their chatrooms function?

More specifically, [how would you handle a situation where they try to bully you into accepting that their actions (abusive language, profanity, etc.) are acceptable as long as nobody complains](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323484/a-cause-for-self-moderation-and-query-on-the-events-of-20-may-16). How will you handle situations where they threaten to quit Stack Exchange because moderators *regulate their chat rooms?*

---

In general, how will you handle users who contribute a lot on Stack Overflow, but are belligerent and brusque?

---

Do you think that people have to be *somewhat aware* of how experienced the OP is on Stack Overflow before they raise flags / vote?

Comment: Are you trying to get a three-fer one here?  (Your first question is worth asking, though, even if there have been themes of it asked throughout the years.)

Answer (score 18):

Reusing my submitted question from [2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309753/fall-2015-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/309766#309766) and [2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337191/2016-stack-overflow-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/337239#337239):

I'm mostly interested in close votes that could be seen as opinion themselves. One person's "unclear" might be another persons "good enough". Therefore,

> Your future close-votes will be binding and hold more weight. You will be able to close questions on your own, without the assistance of 4 other community members. With that in mind, will you cast **more** or **fewer** close-votes than today?

If you don't like the wording, the following improvement was suggested, which I think is fine, too:

> Being a moderator you will able to close questions on your own and override other community votes. Will this change how you vote to close questions?

Answer (score 17):

A user is having problems adapting to meta. They don't seem to take feedback into account and repeatedly post unresearched, too broad, poorly worded questions.

They have a sizeable amount of reputation, hence give an impression of being aware of the sites guidelines, but they really disregard everything that is said to them.

It seems (from the comments on their posts from long time users) that the community is generally getting tired of their questions.

- Do you think this falls into the tasks expected of a moderator?
- Is there a line after which you think serious measures should be taken to prevent an obnoxious user from angering the community?

Comment: It almost sounds like you're thinking of someone specific.

Comment: @Don'tPanic It's a lot less direct about thinking of someone specific than it was- And honestly, I've seen a number of users like this pop during my Meta years. So it _could_ be about anyone.

Comment: @Kendra It's true. Maybe I just thought it sounded that way because I thought of someone specific as I was reading it. :)

Comment: well the timing does seem odd @Don'tPanic ;) But it does make it a real scenario and I would be interested to know the response

Answer (score 16):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 15):

A new user wants to leave a comment, but they lack sufficient reputation (50) to leave comments, so instead they post the comment as an answer. The answer is (correctly) flagged as "Not an answer". The would-be comment is however a good one.

As a moderator, you can:

1. Delete the answer
2. Convert the answer to a comment
3. Dismiss the flag

What do you do and why?

Answer (score 12):

As far as I can see, a large part of being a moderator entails handling flags, and a lot of those flags are clear cut: spam, abusive content, Not An Answer, and so on.

What remains are cases where you'll be the judge of how to handle a flag: people who have a problem with how other people behave on the site, where no obvious reaction from the moderator can be prepared, but where you'll have to think of a response on a case-by-case scenario.

What background do you have to keep your emotions out of this? Can you convince us that you'll objectively handle such scenarios?

Answer (score 11):

Since moderators do not have any review queue limit, they are free to conduct as many reviews from the review queue that they can bear.  In light of this, how much weight and emphasis would you put on yourself as a moderator when attempting to clear out the review queues, and why?

Answer (score 11):

[This recent question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363902/2675154)
and the comments on it indicate that there is quite some backlog of flags in the moderator queue. And last year we already had [a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351974/2675154)
on whether the candidates can scale up their work time on that queue if required.

Therefore I'd like to renew the question: Will you be able to *continuously* invest sufficient/reasonable time in the moderator queue?

Answer (score 10):

You find that a user appears to be "gaming" the rules. They appear to be paying careful attention to avoid violating any specific policy, but they are contributing little, if any, lasting value to the site. Their purposes may be different from, or even in conflict with, the long-term goals of SO. How should this be handled? In other words, is SO moderation, if described using ethics terminology, more deontological (rules/means based, enforcing penalties against offenders who Break The Rules as they are written) or utilitarian (doing the greatest good for the greatest number of users/ends based, enforcing penalties against users whose presence or contributions do not bring about the long-term goals of SO)?

An example of this might be a user who does not engage in voting fraud as that term is defined in SO policies and on Meta, but whose voting patterns are very different from standard voting practices - they upvote crappy content and downvote good content.

Answer (score 8):

This question was taken from [last year's election questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352386/2017-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire/352402#352402).

> Due to your status and actions as moderator and no matter how
> reasonable your conduct, you will be personally insulted more
> frequently, will have your competence questioned more publicly, and
> will be more exposed to negative sentiments. How will you cope with
> this negative pressure long-term when it comes from many users?

This offers a contrast from the typical questions, showing a different side of the moderators than what is shown onsite, and addresses an issue that may, in the short- or long-run, affect their performance.

Comment: Mods usually get *lovely, polite responses* when they warn / suspend users :P. They get asked about their mental health, family etc. Isn't that just cute?

Comment: @TheLostMind It might be nice to see how well moderator candidates could take that sort of stuff. That is, if there were a way to find out other than the, um, obvious way...

Comment: @AndrewMyers - Well, if you are planning on being a mod, that's the first thing one needs to be mentally prepared for

Answer (score 7):

What, if any, additional moderation tools do you think should be opened to the community to reduce the burden on the moderators?

Comment: Interesting question, but I'm not sure how a candiate can know what tools they *will* have as a moderator, moderator tools are secret (even if you get some glimps now and then from screenshots). Hence this question probably would be more interesting to ask to experienced moderators.

Comment: As Petter says, this might actually be a good general Meta question to promote discussion among moderators and the community. There's a related discussion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251175/stack-overflow-is-not-yet-a-vast-wasteland-a-history-of-moderator-tooling), but I don't know if it covers the same area.

Comment: Even if what they come up with is not an actual tool available to moderators today, it would allow me as a voter to consider what their first priority might be if elected.

Answer (score 3):

From the election last year, by [Baum mit Augen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351994):

> Say you just performed a simple moderator action, like closing a question and leaving a comment explaining why.
>
> The question's owner disagrees with your decision, flags your comment as "no longer needed" and replies with a comment that should be flagged as "rude or abusive".
>
> Do you handle the situation yourself or do you wait for another mod to clean up?
>
> If you handle it yourself, do you just dismiss their flag, delete their comment and move on or do take further action?

Comment: Not sure how answers to this will meaningfully distinguish between candidates.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I haven't really thought abaout that, the main reason why I brought it up is that it was a question from [last years election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352386/2017-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire/).

Comment: I didn't like it last year, either. ;)

Answer (score -4):

> Prior to your nomination, you have led the community through answers, edits, meta discussions, or by working the queues. But as a moderator, you will spend a large chunk of your time on flags. How do you expect will this change your role in the community?

---

(Nominees come with a variety of expectations about moderatorship. But what I've seen with many many moderators is that the ways how they contribute drastically changes after their election – often in ways that they did not seem to imagine in their nomination text. In many ways, it is actually easier to contribute if you're *not* a mod. So I am suggesting this question in order to see where a nominee wants to go, and whether moderatorship will actually get them there.)

Answer (score -6):

Should moderators be contributing content to the site during the terms of their moderation? By contributing content, I am speaking primarily about asking and answering questions. Should moderators ask and answer questions as they would have if they were not moderators, or should moderators minimize new content contributions and concentrate primarily on moderation activities?

Comment: I can't tell if the downvotes on this mean "What a dumb question", "This question has been asked before", "This question has nothing to do with the election", "This question doesn't exactly invite thought-provoking answers", "Good question; my answer is no", "Good question; my answer is yes", or "Does this question have an agenda?"

Comment: I personally would like to hear candidates' and even incumbent moderators' thoughts on this.

Comment: I find this question personally interesting. The diamond symbol does attract attention and gives a sign of "trust". Depending on the person's point of view, it could be seen as an easy way to gain more rep. Though, being moderator does not stipulate spending the whole day moderating, but only a certain amount of time each day. It all comes down to the moderator's intentions.

Comment: One of very few actually thought-provoking questions, going beyond job-interview boilerplate "how would you handle ${outrageous_scenario} if it happened?" Doesn't look like this is going to make it to the questionnaire; maybe you should just post it as a general Meta question.

Comment: This is an interesting, thought-provoking question, but I don't think the answers will help me decide who to vote for.  I agree with Josh Caswell that it might make a good standalone question (probably after the election business has died down?).

Comment: @BoltClock:  I don't find it particularly thought-provoking.  Moderators are still users of the site.  They still contribute to the site.  To think that they would somehow be afforded *less* rights to use the site because they're a moderator is more befuddling than interesting.

Answer (score -7):

If you came across a comment with a lot of positive votes, what criteria would you use to decide that it should be moved to answer, or kept as a comment, or even eventually deleted?

Comment: You don't have to be a moderator to move a comment to an answer.  Copy and paste the comment and post it as a Community Wiki with a reference to the original comment.

Comment: Ofcourse not. It's a general question of typical moderating action.

Comment: I'd actually consider it highly *atypical*, frankly.  There are ways to cajole the commentator to make it into an answer but ultimately it's not something only a diamond moderator can do.

Comment: Are these questions only for Diamond moderator actions? If so, I'll delete it. I didn't read that into the original post.

Comment: Also, there are other things that happen to comments than them being moved into an answer. Some are obviously not an answer though they are great comments. At times, mods go through and clean up comments, but decide to leave a few relevant gems.

Comment: Without the first sub-question ("have you made any comments"), your question would improve a bit. The first part is completely unrelated to the second part and to mod duties.

Comment: Can't hurt I guess. <edited>

Answer (score -10):

A question from a [previous election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309847/3956566).

> A user flags a post or comment as rude or offensive to a minority
>   group, or as a member of a minority group. You know little about the
>   issues facing this minority group and the post would not be offensive
>   to the majority of users.
>
> What do you do?

Comment: It's hard to write this sort of thing in a way that doesn't seem antagonistic (note, I'm not answering your question here, I'm trying to help you word it a bit more effectively). The problem you're trying to suss out is that the moderator _does not know_ of issues facing the group, so they can't be aware of _what they don't know_ unless it has been pointed out to them. I think a better question might be something like "What do you feel is a good strategy to help ensure unconscious biases don't detract from the value and effectiveness of moderation?" -- something along that line?

Comment: @Tim Post: "they can't be aware of what they don't know unless it has been pointed out to them" That's what the flag is for - making them aware. The question here is what the moderator does with the content taking into account the realization that the content may be objectionable to a group of people.

Comment: @TimPost interesting response to this question - your take on it is something different - cognitive biases (unconscious and the person isn't aware of it) - this is about say - someone from Country A + Religion X is upset and moderator knows nothing about this - it was used in a [previous election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310356/fall-2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire). It really is a exemplar of the fickleness of meta.

Comment: @BoltClock yes perfect explanation!

Answer (score -13):

What will you do to help attract new users while at the same time stop them from posting bad posts, duplicates, spam etc. For context of this question just have a look at the number of new users that stay active on the site and we have a big problem, that newbies are not being active on the site despite the record numbers of new users. The mentor program was a start but involved way to much effort.

What would be your solution to this problem?

Comment: I feel like this kind of question falls *firmly* into the category of paid Community Manager territory, not unpaid, volunteer moderator territory.

Answer (score -18):

Suppose you make a mistake. A high-rep user whose contributions you value takes objection and (after some drama) quits Stack Overflow, blaming you.

How do you handle it on a personal level?

If it happens again six months later, how would you handle it?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a likely situation for a few reasons. A high-rep user would have likely been on the site for a while, and is not likely to leave on the basis of one mistake from a moderator. It would have to be a major mistake to cause this much drama. And for drama to the magnitude you're describing, a more likely outcome is that other mods would be involved and reverse the mistake.

Comment: I agree that this doesn't really seem like a plausible scenario. If it's a mistake, presumably it would be corrected and nobody is going to rage-quit over it.

Answer (score -45):

Should moderators vote on posts according to their own opinions? That is, is it appropriate for a moderator to upvote or downvote content according to their own personal viewpoint on whether or not it is useful, or should moderators limit their voting activity to only the most egregious cases of stellar or abysmal content (or even avoid voting entirely)? Voting is anonymous, but if it becomes known or is alleged that a moderator upvoted or downvoted a specific post in a manner that could be interpreted as a sign of potential favoritism, is that acceptable as long as no actual voting fraud was committed by the moderator? Another way to ask this question is to ask whether votes by moderators reflect, or should reflect, their own opinions or the opinions of Stack Exchange and/or the Stack Overflow Moderation Team.

Comment: When has a moderator ever *voted* on content that hasn't been related to their opinions or expertise?  It's different when they close questions for personal motives or grudges, but that's not what you're asking here...

Comment: @Makoto I'm not saying that a moderator ever has - it's just a question.

Comment: Is it acceptable for moderators to kill kittens? I'm not saying that a moderator ever has - it's just a question. (PS The answer is yes, kittens are evil so it's fine for anyone to murder them)

Answer (score -83):

Is gender important and do you think it matters if you're a man or a woman when moderating?

Comment: How does this qualify as a moderator question exactly?

Comment: @Makoto It was noted during the last election that certain individuals used gender as part of their motive for being a moderator. I'd like to know if those that run, believe it to be of importance when moderating.

Comment: ...but you can't infer gender online unless it's volunteered.  Even my pseudonym "Makoto" is a gender-neutral name in Japanese.  I get that tone and professionalism matter, but this doesn't feel like the right question to be asking...

Comment: Remind me to ask this question to my friends Yuri, Kelly, Sharon, Ashley, and Morgan.

Comment: Call me rude, but I'm a bit happy at the downvotes here. It is a sign that gender shouldn't be part of the election. So, when any candidate mentions about gender, we can say that SO moderator candidates must not be voted based on that fact.

Comment: @Makoto: That's precisely the point. Some candidates volunteer their gender information and use it as a selling point for their nomination, i.e. "vote for me because I'm a woman and can give women the representation they need"

Comment: @BhargavRao it's certainly good to see that a lot of people don't like this question and that they take the opinion that gender should **not** be a motive. I hope to see none of it during the election or I'll be pulling them up about it.

Comment: Maybe this question should be asked in a different way. Something like "Do you believe minorities should be proportionally represented among the Stack Overflow moderators? Do you belong to a minority group that could bring a minority viewpoint to the moderator team?"

Comment: @S.L. Barth: Those are different questions entirely to this one, but are far better, I agree.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks! I'll consider adding them. Need to think a little about the wording. _If_ I'm going to add this as a candidate question, I'd like it to be asked as neutral as possible.

Comment: @S.L. Barth: On the other hand, if you don't want to have to deal with the inevitable comment fight flooding your notifications...

Comment: @S.L.Barth yes they are good questions, get them asked. I was making a point. I'll admit, it probably could have been worded better but I prefer to be blunt.

Comment: This question is too vague, and it sounds like you have a political axe to grind. Can you expand it to illustrate a way in which a moderator's gender might affect their moderation? At present, the most obvious interpretation is that you think some genders can moderator better than others, though I don't think that's what you're getting at.

Comment: @BhargavRao: I'm supportive of gender discussions, and I'm cautiously on the positive discrimination side of the fence. I downvoted this answer because I think it's not a good question (see above).

Comment: @halfer it isn't what I'm getting at. For me gender has no place when moderating and should never come into it however it was used as a motive during the last election as illustrated by BoltClock's comment and I found it unprofessional to say the least. I don't personally care what gender you are as long as you are fair. Make it about gender though and you're instantly on the wrong track as a moderator. As I said, I'm making a point so yes you could say I have an "axe to grind".

Comment: @halfer I'd like to add that I'm not attempting to be hostile here (read back over my last comment and it looked a little like that) and I'm not trying to troll (which I appreciate that it may look like I am). That said I don't think editing it into shape is worthwhile at this point.

Comment: @Bugs: righto, thanks for explaining, and I didn't take it as hostile. I think it is good to elucidate. I wonder if you may find the question counterproductive though - if you manage to get potential moderators who are female to admit to volunteering because they are in favour of redressing the gender balance, then some folks may vote for them because of that, which presumably you'd not be in favour of! While I'd welcome gender balance in the moderation team, this issues tends to be so "hot button" that it can eclipse other important issues.

Comment: @halfer you make a very good point, at least one I can't argue against anyway

Comment: Also, as it stands, the question feels like it is aimed at women (or female candidacies). It could be rewritten, but might still attempt to "weed out" progressive folks who are in favour of gender discussions and/or gender balancing initiatives. That sounds like a political filtering which makes me uncomfortable in a way I can't quite put my finger on. I agree the key issue for a prospective moderator is whether they are fair, but their internal belief system probably informs that sense of fairness a great deal.

Comment: @halfer I don't see how it is aimed at women. Should the OP have written it as *if you're a woman or a man when moderating?* instead?

Comment: And BTW, I've not voted on the post because I feel that it's a good question to be asked, but upvoting it would imply gender is an issue in the upcoming elections.

Comment: @S.L.Barth totally agree- a more general question would be better. It's not a good idea to have such specific examples - as we could have a question like that about any programming "minority" group.

Comment: @Bugs you're the one stirring the gender pot- the election hasn't even started and you posted a question you didn't think was good to make a point. There's been 3 female candidates ever. People are allowed to have their opinions about whether it would be good to have female representation and allowed to voice that. It's not for you to police people's opinions. yes you can voice yours, but people are also allowed to voice theirs. It seems to me you've come into this election spoiling for a fight. As you said **I'm not trying to troll (which I appreciate that it may look like I am)**

Comment: _"People are allowed to have their opinions about whether it would be good to have female representation and allowed to voice that."_ Sure, @YvetteColomb. But SO is not the place for a political agenda, and an nomination ___absolutely___ shouldn't be about electing someone because of whatever gender they identify as. _That_ is the point of this question. I'm not sure why you're bringing up the 3 female candidates. The question made sure not to mention a specific gender.

Comment: @Cerbrus because this entire post is specifically about me. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364236/the-election-gender-debate-has-commenced-how-can-we-resolve-this Added link for Bugs et al so you know it's being discussed. Transparency

Comment: Alright everyone, a new thread has spawned, let's not have two conversations going at once now.

Comment: unwanted question